# Where could I find road data for counties in the state of Florida

Tags: geospatial, us-census, transportation, data-mapping

I would like to know about websites from I could download roads data for counties in the State of Florida. I was able to find Tiger shapefiles for each county in every state in the US. However the data is not very accurate especially when mapped with parcel data for these counties. Are there websites for the individual counties from where I could download the roads data. The data would need to include local county roads as well as interstate highways.

Counties I am particularly interested in are:
Hillsborough, Osceola, Pasco, Pinellas, Manatee, Polk and Lake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this from Openstreetmap.

See [Downloading data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) or [Country and area extraction](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) on the Openstreetmap wiki for details on how to do this.